# android mediaplayer streaming FileNotFoundException No content provider

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, streaming, android-mediaplayer

My android.media.MediaPlayer throws a FileNotFoundException No content provider sometimes when it tries to prepareAsync()

When I curl the same command, the file downloads and I can play on my desktop.

All the files are 3gpg format.

When I try and stream specific files. The player works for 80% of all files, but for files bigger than 2 mb, I sometimes get the below exception.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   https://www.boom.com:443/api/mobile/1/getRecording/185/ at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1117)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:970)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:897)
>   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1112) at
>   com.killesk.boom.MediaPlayerAbstract.attachAudio(MediaPlayerAbstract.java:121)
>   at
>   com.killesk.boom.MediaPlayerAbstract.asyncGetActivityModelLatestDetailedRecordingsPostMethodScuess(MediaPlayerAbstract.java:451)
>   at
>   com.killesk.boom.network.asynctask.AsyncTaskGetActivityModelLatestDetailedRecordings.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskGetActivityModelLatestDetailedRecordings.java:94)
>   at
>   com.killesk.boom.network.asynctask.AsyncTaskGetActivityModelLatestDetailedRecordings.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskGetActivityModelLatestDetailedRecordings.java:34)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

I've checked the files that fail on the server and they play perfectly after I download them manually. Pretty much this is my code:

```
String url = AndroidPhoneProperties.REST_API +
                AndroidPhoneProperties.POST_GETRECORDING + File.separator +
                recordingServerID + File.separator;

        byte[] toEncrypt = (user.getEmail() + ":" + user.getPassword()).getBytes();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            URL boom = new URL(url);
            URLConnection con = boom.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            con.getContent();
            Uri uriBoom = Uri.parse(con.getURL().toString());
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uriBoom, headers);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            showMessage("You might not set the URI correctly!");
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            showMessage("You might not set the URI correctly!");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            showMessage("You might not set the URI correctly!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            showMessage("You might not set the URI correctly!");
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                enableView(true, play);
                play.setAlpha(AndroidPhoneProperties.ENABLED_ALPHA_RATE);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                showMessage("Problem with the stream");
                return false;
            }
        });

        dismissDialog();
```

I have a funny feeling it's to do with not giving enough time to start steaming the file, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: How can you resolve it?

Comment: I didn't really solve it. I had a for loop that tried to upload the file 4 times. At the second or third attempt, it went up. Sorry it does not fix it, but It's the only thing I found worked